# How can I get the unique values of a column and turn them into new columns using SELECT?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following dataset, that basically is the number of downloads every app had per day (numbers are not real, obviously)

| date | app_name | downloads |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | Facebook | 1000 |
| 2021-01-02 | Twitter | 2000 |
| 2021-01-02 | Reddit | 500 |
| 2021-01-03 | Facebook | 3000 |
| 2021-01-03 | Twitter | 2500 |
| 2021-01-03 | Reddit | 800 |
| 2021-01-04 | Facebook | 2000 |
| 2021-01-04 | Twitter | 750 |
| 2021-01-04 | Reddit | 1000 |

I need to query `DISTINCT` days and all the three apps, making each one of them a column, like the table bellow:

| date | Facebook | Twitter | Reddit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | 1000 | 2000 | 500 |
| 2021-01-03 | 3000 | 2500 | 800 |
| 2021-01-04 | 2000 | 750 | 1000 |

I managed to do that, but my query ended up as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DATE,
    SUM(facebook) AS fb,
    SUM(twitter) AS tw,
    SUM(reddit) AS rd
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         dt AS DATE,
         IF (app = 'facebook', SUM(downloads), 0) AS facebook,
         IF (app = 'twitter', SUM(downloads), 0) AS twitter,
         IF (app = 'reddit', SUM(downloads), 0) AS reddit
     FROM
         apps
     GROUP BY 
         1, app
     ORDER BY 
         1 DESC)
GROUP BY 1
```

Is there any way to make it shorter and/or quicker to run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct logic would use `sum(case)`:

```
SELECT dt AS DATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN app = 'facebook' THEN downloads ELSE 0 END) AS facebook,
       SUM(CASE WHEN app = 'twitter'THEN downloads ELSE 0 END) AS twitter,
       SUM(CASE WHEN app = 'reddit'THEN downloads ELSE 0 END) AS reddit
FROM apps
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select *
from data
pivot (sum(downloads) for app_name in ('Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Reddit'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]